# Compactar tudo por SSH exceto uma pasta no Centos7

Tags: centos, ssh, arquivo-zip

Gostaria de compactar tudo em *zip*, ou seja todo conteúdo do meu *public_html* porém, preciso que a pasta files não seja adicionada para compressão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para um "**comando de uma linha**" você precisará saber o path completo de todos os diretórios que não quer incluir no zip.

Estrutura de exemplo:

```
pasta1
    a.txt
    b.txt
    pasta2
        c.txt
        d.txt
    pasta3
        e.txt
        f.txt
    pasta4
        g.txt
        h.txt
```

No comando a seguir, estou mandando **não** compactar as pastas `pasta2` e `pasta3`:

```
zip -r novoZip.zip pasta1 -x pasta1/pasta2/\* pasta1/pasta3/\*
```

O meu arquivo `novoZip.zip` ficará assim:

```
pasta1
    a.txt
    b.txt
    pasta4
        g.txt
        h.txt
```

Comment: E seu eu tiver assim Estou dentro da pasta public_html/ porem quero compactar tudo dentro dela exceto a pasta files/ ? EU JA ESTANDO DENTRO DA public_html